# Facebook Login within Mobile App

Tags: android, iphone, facebook

I am planning to integrate "Login With Facebook" feature into my iPhone/Android App; and I have a PHP back-end for maintaining user details.

I am confused as to what is the standard way in which this feature should be implemented?

Is it that - After the user gets successfully authenticated by Facebook, should I fetch his/her details and ask him for a password to register him to my back-end or is there something else which needs to be done & I am not aware.

Please suggest the standard way of implementing this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Login with facebook button

1. Redirect a new user to facebook for required permissions
2. Prefill your register form with details from facebook and a password for your site.
3. Save details of the user in your backend.

### When the connected user logins again

1. Check for active facebook session
2. Get the userID of current facebook user is equal to that saved in your database log him in
3. else  show registration form.

Comment: Your second point is amazing, I mean I would have missed it altogether if I hadn't asked this here.

Answer (score 6):

We had the same situation..

So what I did was:

1. Authenticate the user.
2. Always Fetch the user's info (like name, email, dob etc.)
3. Now send the fb id and email to your server.
4. Server will look up the database to check the existence of fb id and
   name
5. If exist, it indicates that it is a register user. (so you will let
   the user login in to your app)
6. If doesn't exist, it indicates that it is a new user. (so you will
   take the user to
7. Join/signup screen and fill the form with the data you got at step
   2) Just leave the password field empty to let the user choose their password.
8. Now send all details with fb id to your server and after successful response
   let the user login immediately because you don't need to ask the user to open email for                     activation link.

Comment: Wouldn't be an option to use Facebook login on the PHP website also? If the user logs in with facebook on the mobile, he could do the same on the website. He could still fill a registration form for additional data.

Comment: yea then server will do the same as did here in step 4.

Comment: Is it possible to use twitter for a similar authentication ? If yes what should be the unique id used ?

Comment: @AjithMemana twitter name is always a unique string, you can use it in place of unique id.

Comment: But the problem with twitter id is that it can be changed any number of times resulting in server identifying it as a new user. I have found that there is a field user_id which is a variable length(6-9 digit) number. Can i use it as a unique id ? I didn't find anybody mention that anywhere

Comment: Step #4 looks to me a security risk. FB ID and email are publicly available information. Anyone can forged and build a masquerading request.

Comment: @AdilSoomro - Why do you need to store a Password?! Because every time the user will login with the Facebook button and not have to enter a password?!

Comment: @James111 but if they first logged in with fb, and later try to login with email/password. They can login with both methods.

Comment: Ohh right. I was thinking of a Facebook only login! Im currently implementing a login for my App. I'm not going to prompt the user for a password. Im just going to let Facebook do all the work.